# Why use Method Overriding in java

Tags: java, overriding

I'm currently learning about Java and I encountered this particular function called method overriding. When do I need to override something from the parent class if I can just create a new function?

```java
class Animal{
    boolean alive;
    void speak(){
        System.out.println("This animal speaks");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    @Override
    void speak(){
        System.out.println("The dog goes *bark*");
    }
}
```

why is there a need to override a method when I can just make a new method in the dog class?

```java
class Dog extends Animal{
    void bark(){
        System.out.println("The dog goes *bark*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You override a method when you have a class hierarchy, as you do, where there is a sensible default behaviour which many of your subclasses will want to use, but some subclasses need different behaviour *and* you want to call the method using a reference of the base class.

If I had code like:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
d.speak();
```

Then just implementing `bark()` would be fine, because `d` is always a `Dog`.
But when I have code like this:

```
Animal a;
if (...) {
 a = new Dog();
} else {
 a = new Cat();
}
a.speak();
```

Then we have to override a method. If the subclasses had a new method (like your `bark()`) which wasn't present on `Animal` we wouldn't be able to call it, because `a` is an `Animal` -- the actual object it refers to might be a `Dog` or a `Cat`.

Comment: Ohhh I see, I think I somewhat understand the use of overriding, your explanation was really easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

If you make a new method bark for your Dog class instead of overriding speak, then you also have to add code to detect that youre dealing with a dog, then cast it to a Dog type, then call bark. You get a program that has a bunch of very specific code that has to handle each concrete type individually, and the workflow has to be updated every time you add a new subclass. There is no abstraction or generality.

The idea behind polymorphism is that your program shouldn't have to worry about which objects are dogs and which are cats, it just handles animals, and lets the subclasses take care of the details for themselves. The program stays at a high level and tells the animals to speak, the specific animals' subclasses decide whether to bark or meow. So if you introduce a new animal subclass the code handling animals doesn't change.

Comment: Does that mean that using overriding makes the code more flexible?, in a sense that I don't need to create separate functions for each animals such as bark, meow, roar etc. and just override the speak function from the parent class to suit that specific animal

Comment: @Kookaburra: it means there is less code because the code using the animals doesn't have to address differences between the animals.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is needed for polymorphism, which is the ability to use subclass instead of superclass anywhere superclass is required. So, let's say you have a method where you need to pass an animal and that method goes like

```
makeAnimalSpeak(Animal a){
  a.speak();
}
```

Later you want to call that method and pass there specifically Dog, not generic animal, and want to make that Dog bark.
So, you go:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
makeAnimalSpeak(dog);
```

Here is the thing: makeAnimalSpeak() doesn't and can't call dog.bark() It calls animal.speak() because Animal and all of its subclasses have speak() method. So, if you want your Dog bark using makeAnimalSpeak() method, you can override speak() method. This way you can have general class Animal and only one method that works for every subclass of animal while customizing the way each subclass speaks.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I need to study more about polymorphism to get a better understanding about overriding,

Answer (score 0):

You can test at class Dog,  what is your output when you call speak() method.

- case 1: class dog not override method speak() of class Animal ?
- case 2: class dog override method speak() of class Animal ?

That is a difference, there are many other difference, and I think you should learn more about it